# Cannot import .sql to PostgreSQL. Syntax error

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Probably a very simple error but I cannot work it out for the life of me. Basically, I am loading a .sql dump into a postgres DB using

```
psql testdb< C:\Users\Callum\Desktop\backup.sql
```

However, I get the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table1`;
                             ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE `table2` (
                     ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: LOCK TABLES `table3` WRITE;
```

I have been trying to work this out for days and could not find any anwsers online.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you importing from MySQL? You don't need backticks here, you can take them out.

Comment: It could potentially be an mySQL database but I was delivered a SchemaSpy report stating that it was a postgresSQL db. I will give mySQL a try in that case.